# Sorry, user "user" is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get update' as root on

Tags: debian, roles, sudo, apt-get

I've installed Debian 7 and just executed `sudo apt-get update` and got this error:

```
Sorry, user xsma is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get update' as root on ACS.ACS
```

my user is "xsma" and  "ACS" is the name of the computer.

Comment: Can you actually run it as root?

Comment: earlier, i could, but trying to solve this, i've made some changes and now even with root, it doesn't work, even after going back to the default configuration i don't understand!

Comment: Does it work if you actually log in as root (thus bypassing `sudo`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just solved this by [reading Debian sudo page](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo) with two steps:
1) add the user to be sudo to the sudo group.
2) log out and log back in to gain that group's permissions.

Debian page said use: `# adduser xsma sudo`, while I had used `# vigr` and `# vigr -s`.

Comment: This page https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user says `sudo usermod -a -G sudo username`

Answer (score -1):

In linux,
For any other linux distribution,  give the command in terminal`

> sudo visudo
> It gives super access to look codes of /usr/sbin/ (dir)
> go down,
> you can initialise any your own commands,file access,group and user privilege
> without root access
> initialise like this "(Your queries) ("ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL " ,"You can costemize by your own needs" )

`